# Error : The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, context.xml, meta-inf

The following is my `context.xml` file in the `META-INF` directory of my project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/poll"/>

<Resource name="jdbc/PollDatasource" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
 driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
 url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/poll database;create=true"
 username="suhail" password="suhail"
 maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />
```

But when I try to deploy/run the project netbeans produces the following error :

```
[Fatal Error] :4:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be 
well-formed.
W:\UnderTest\NetbeansCurrent\poll\nbproject\build-impl.xml:721: Deployment error: 
Tomcat configuration file 
W:\UnderTest\NetbeansCurrent\poll\web\META-INF\context.xml seems to be broken.
Please make sure it is parseable and valid.
See the server log for details.
```

Why do I get this error ? I have added the database information in the `context.xml`.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your context.xml, take out the / right before the > in your Context tag and add the end tag after the Resource.  Your Resource should be defined **within** your Context.

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/poll" >

    <Resource name="jdbc/PollDatasource" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
     url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/poll database;create=true"
     username="suhail" password="suhail"
     maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />

</Context>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you please explain the attribute `antiJarLocking`

Comment: Check out the answers to your own question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607009/what-is-antijarlocking-attribute